# Cannot resolve methods on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I use onMeasure:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
    final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null) {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        mPreviewSize = getBestPreviewSize(width, height, parameters);
    }
}
```

Android Studio tells me "*Cannot resolve method*" for **getSuggestedMinimumWidth()**, **getSuggestedMinimumHeight()** and **setMeasuredDimension()**

Of course I did all the necessary import.

Any ideas?

Comment: you did the "import", but did you do the "extends"?

Comment: OMG no… class is **public class MainActivity extends Activity**, how can i extend on _viewgroup_ (it's what I need, right?)?

Comment: You have to extend "a" View. The methods are protected so the only way of using them is extending the View.